# Infinite gas estimate caused by Internal function type

Tags: solidity, remix, solc, gas-estimate

When I flag a simple function with the type *internal*, remix throws an infinite gas estimate warning. Without this type, everything is fine. Please, do you know why?

`function half(uint a) {
          uint b = a/2;
          //...
}`-> Gas estimate for "half(uint256)": "230"

`function half(uint a) internal {
          uint b = a/2;
          //...
}` -> Gas estimate for "half(uint256)": "infinite"

Comment: "Because of this I can't deploy my contract." Compiler warnings generally don't prevent you from deploying your contract. Can you explain why you can't deploy?

Comment: my bad, in the deployer I wrote I was checking gas first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything else going on in the function because I didn't have this issue in remix.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract StackEthereumTholoz {

    function start(uint _int) public pure returns (uint) {
        return half(_int);
    }

    function half(uint _a) internal pure returns (uint) {
        uint b = _a/2;  
        return b;
    }

}
```

Gas: 72

---

#### [Update 1]

So, based on your code (and minimal example code), when an `internal` contract is actually not used, Remix cannot actually calculate the gas cost. It will automatically set it as infinite as a default.

Comment: Hi ! Here is my minimum example: ```pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

  contract Infinite  {

      function half(uint a) internal{
          uint b = a/2;

      }
}``` Even when I add pure it keeps throwing Infinite gas estimate

Comment: @Tholoz Answer updated to explain why you get infinite with that minimum example.